# need to find out count how many times 'a' used in a string using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

@char = 'abbhsaihuakkdjaiejjaklfdakdjdja'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method uses `len()` and `replace()`:

```
select (len(@char) - len(replace(@char, 'a', ''))) as num_a
```

Comment: great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DATALENGTH`

```
DECLARE @tosearch VARCHAR(MAX)='a';
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX)='abbhsaihuakkdjaiejjaklfdakdjdja';


SELECT (DATALENGTH(@string)-DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@string,@tosearch,'')))/DATALENGTH(@tosearch)  
AS a_count
```